# dom vs sax vs stax when you need entire file anyway

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, sax, stax

I read that stax and sax are faster then DOM because they don't have to process the entire xml file. I saw speed comparisons with x number of files, but they didn't specify how much of the file they were accessing each time. If my understanding is correct, I'd assume that needing the entire file is the best case for DOM and the worst case for the parse-as-you-go methods.

[Collada files (.dae)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COLLADA) typically need all the information in the file every time its used.
So what if you're going to use basically everything stored in the xml file, every time you access it. Assuming files aren't too large, is DOM preferable in that case?

Comment: if you're loading one file and then accessing it multiple times, then the load-it-all-into-ram overhead of DOM is acceptable. If you're accessing MULTIPLE files only once, then the other options may be better, since they don't suck up as much memory each for what is essentially going to be a one-shot-per-file operation.

Comment: Which one to use depends on what you're doing with the data after loading.  If you need to navigate through the document in its original structured form you might be best served by loading the DOM. However, if you can reduce the data to a form that speeds up access by your code, you are better off using sax to build your in-memory data structure.  We can't tell from what you've described so far which method would be better, and it may not make a difference anyway.

Comment: Sorry, like a collada file I am navigating to every last bit of the file and copying everything into variables (then passing them off to opengl).

Comment: If your objective is to optimize for time (and you really _need_ to), then an event-based approach would be best for this case.

Comment: The above is the answer I was looking for.